# Stack DIVs horizontally

Tags: html, css, fluid

I have this fragment of HTML:

```
<style>
    #top, #left, #right
    {
        border: 1pt solid silver;
        margin: 3px;
    }
    #left
    {
        float: left;
        width:50%;
    }
    #right
    {
        float: right;
        width:50%;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="top">Text</div>
    <div id="left">Text</div>
    <div id="right">Text</div>
</div>
```

I want the "left" and "right" divs to take the entire width of the screen, so I set their width to 50% each.

For some reason, the "left" and "right" divs overlap -- the "right" div is under the "left" div. What is the correct way to style these divs so they are displayed side-by-side and occupy the entire width of the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/ER8pR/1/

CSS:

```
   #top, #left>div, #right>div
    {
        border: 1pt solid silver;
        margin: 3px;
    }
    #left
    {
        float: left;
        width:50%;
    }
    #right
    {
        float: right;
        width:50%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="top">Text</div>
    <div id="left"><div>Text</div></div>
    <div id="right"><div>Text</div></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the total widths of `#left` and `#top` are

```
margin-left + border-left + padding-left + width + padding-right + border-right + margin-right
```

In your case, `3px+1px+0+50%+0+1px+3px` = `50% + 8px`, so if you sum them you get `100% + 16px`, which is greater than `100%`.

You can fix it removing all margins, paddings and borders and creating a new `<div>` inside them with `width:auto` and the margins, paddings and borders that you want.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution with one edit -- had to switch #left>div, #right>div to #left div, #right div, so it works in IE7. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird, the child selector should work on IE7 (but it doesn't on IE 6). See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t11

Comment: Sorry, double-checking relieved it was IE8 where > didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough space for them to align, because they each take 50% to which you have to add the four 3px margins, so the total takes 100% + 12px, and thus can't fit aligned.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your #left and #right..

div's are blocks and take up the whole row, even if theyre given a width! so make them inline-blocks so that they will stack horizontally too

Comment: and your widths/borders will come into play...you might need to reduce them from 50% to 49%, or something similar..i would suggest having no style in the position div's and add styles to div's within the position div to get the full effect.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your border and margins 50% + 1px on the left and 1px on the right equal more than 50%.
Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to make sure your div is 50%, not more with the border.
 See this example http://jsfiddle.net/zvMTN/

Answer (score 0):

That problem you are having is that you have set borders and margins on these div's so they will note stay side-by-side at 50% width.  You should probably use something like 48% for your widths if you are not working within a fixed-width container.